# ActionView::MissingTemplate Error on Rails 3.1 Application on Site5 hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionview

Hello Everyone,
               I am experiencing a strange problem when deploying a Rails 3.1 application running on phusion passenger.The problem have been bugging me for over 3 days now and I cannot seem to debug the error which is causing this error.

In controllers I have a folder by the name of admin and it contains controllers that are specific to backend admin section only. The routes are defined like this in the routes.rb file :

```
namespace  :admin do
    resources :users
    match "dashboard/show" => "dashboard#show"
    match "access/login" => "access#login"
    match "access/attempt_login" => "access#attempt_login"
    root :to => "access#login"
end
```

There is no error at all when the application is running in development environment on my mac however the application is giving 500 internal error when the application is deployed via capistrano. Please see the error below :

```
Started GET "/admin" for 110.39.204.79 at Sun Mar 04 06:48:23 -0600 2012
  Processing by Admin::AccessController#login as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admin/access/login with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/devacity/acitywithquirk/releases/20120304124458/app/views"
  * "/home/devacity/acitywithquirk/releases/20120304124458/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
  * "/home/devacity/acitywithquirk/releases/20120304124458"

Started GET "/admin/dashboard" for 114.76.86.94 at Mon Mar 05 15:15:19 -0600 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/dashboard"):
  * "/"
):
  app/controllers/admin/access_controller.rb:14:in `login'
```

I have spent copious amount of time in trying to resolve the issue but it I am not able to.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are your sure the view is on your remote server ?

Comment: Do you have an `app/views/admin/access/login.html.erb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may check your svn commit. If not added to svn, it won't be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists.  Also: I've had this error before when I was using haml, but it was only in the assets group, so not included on production (note that your formats only include erb and builder).  Once I moved haml-rails out of the :assets group in the Gemfile it worked fine.